# Google sign in ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift3, subscript

`application:openURL:options:` method of app delegate. 
The method should call the `handleURL` method of the `GIDSignIn` instance, 
which will properly handle the URL that your application receives 
at the end of the authentication process.

Directly copied from firebase guide docs but still has errors.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url as URL!, sourceApplication: 
        options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]  //Error is here
        //Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' error is shown.

        as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a few issues. The delegate method should have the following signature in Swift 3:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

and the whole method would be:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Comment: I get Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error in App Delegate after running the application and clicking the google signin button

Comment: Are `_` & `open` external parameter names? Why doesn't `options` have an external parameter name?

Comment: @Honey Those are the argument labels used by callers of the method. The `_` means that no name is provided for the parameter. And if argument has no separate label (like `options`), then you use the parameter name as the argument label. This is all covered in Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book for Swift 3.

Comment: @rmandy Isn't Google sign in functions released by Firebase itself?? I have converted my every codes to swift 3 but still the google sign in button does not work.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question since you are dealing with a new issue. Be sure you provide relevant code and complete details about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple URL schemes along with Google Sign In, use it like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

}
```